# Excel tie colums to the first column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In my table (I have an example below), I import the first 2 columns from another sheet that changes the data weekly. My problem is that I want to tie the other columns (like Age) to the first columns. I have a button that I press to import the first 2 columns and when the data changes (other are added or the order is changed), the data from the other columns stay the same (like after the import, John changed with Samara, the age will remain the same, not on the correct person).
The age column is populated when the user uses a form, so I cannot use any VLOOKUP.
Is there something I could do to prevent that change?

[image]

Comment: *Where* is the data with people's age? You should not be making changes to a sheet that contains raw data (i.e. the data provided by the form you mention). Work on a different sheet instead.

Comment: Have you looked into `dictionaries` to link the age data to the correct name? You could even link more columns to one name by joining the values, and later splitting them using the `split` function

Comment: ? why are you importing the first two columns, it looks like you are updating a personnel listing, you should be adding new people to the bottom of the data. One way is to test the data you are copying, with the current data in the destination ws, and if not there, then copy the two cells and paste the data at the bottom of the data in your destination ws.

Comment: @GMalc I was also thinking about that, but I'm new to VBA and I thought maybe there's a simpler way to do it. Do you have any idea how I should start doing my code?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad That was a simple example, the client uses an userform to add the data in that column, whereas the first 2 column are imported from another sheet in the workbook

Comment: How about just re-importing every time a change is made so you are sure the data is connected to its respectful owner? Hard to give solid advice without a proper example file

Comment: @TimStack I need to import the first 2 columns each week, because they change. The age is not on the import, this is why it is added manually. I thought about importing it with copy paste because it was the simplest way for me to do it. But when the import changes, so the data and the order, while the Age column remains unthouched because it is not linked to anything.

Comment: Keep the age data in a separate sheet and use `VLOOKUP` so it updates automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you only import columns A and B, and the information in Column C only exists in this current workbook. As such, it can't be imported.

If that's correct, then there are a couple of steps to take.

1. Save the link between the ID number and the age
2. Import the data
3. Reset the age based on the saved information

The approach that I took was to use a Dictionary object because these are relatively efficient and work great when storing key-value pairs. In the code below, I save the ID as the key, and the Age as the value. I then import the new information. Then I reset the age. Depending on how you're doing the import, you may be able to combine steps 2 and 3, but that's harder to say without seeing the code. See below, and let us know if you need any more help or information.

```
Sub StoreAgeInformation()
    Dim oDict As Object
    Dim rng As Range 'Range with the ID Primary Key
    Dim rIterator As Range

    'Offset to the ID column (in this case, we are saving the
    'data that is 2 columns to the right
    Const COL_OFFSET As Integer = 2

    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'Change the range to match your data (only need the ID column)
    Set rng = Range("A2:A4")

    For Each rIterator In rng
        'If the ID is not already in the dictionary, then add it
        If Not oDict.exists(rIterator.Value2) Then
            'Add: KEY, VALUE
            oDict.Add rIterator.Value2, rIterator.Offset(, COL_OFFSET).Value2
        End If
    Next rIterator

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' RUN IMPORT CODE HERE
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    'Redefine the range in case new rows have been added or deleted
    Set rng = Range("A2:A6")


    For Each rIterator In rng
        If oDict.exists(rIterator.Value2) Then
            rIterator.Offset(, COL_OFFSET).Value2 = oDict(rIterator.Value2)
        Else
            'If a new row, then the age is set to 0
            rIterator.Offset(, COL_OFFSET).Value2 = 0
        End If
    Next rIterator

End Sub
```